# Events for ANY form on a page (not specific to a single form)

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on a Chrome extension and what I want to do is have an event handler for when the user does an action on ANY form.

So imagine I don't know the name of the form but I want to have it so when the user submits the form an action is done.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just handle the `onsubmit` for every form on the page.  Loop through all the forms, set your function as the handler.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')
```